# Python : Counting unique values in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to add up the number of equal values in a list. The list looks like this:

```
list = [["APP", "X", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
           ["APP2", "X", "v3", "CN_M", "2"],
           ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
           ["APP2", "Z", "v3", "CN_M", "2"]]
```

etc.

I am mainly concerned with the number of times the 4th field is found.

I am not very experienced in Python. I had already found something about Counter and I tried something with it.

```
from collections import Counter
list = [["APP", "X", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
       ["APP2", "X", "v3", "CN_M", "2"],
       ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
       ["APP2", "Z", "v3", "CN_M", "2"]]

distinct_list=(Counter(list).keys())
```

Without for loop I get nothing from this code, and get an unhashable type back.
Who can push me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the expected result for this data?

Comment: It should be 2. Counting the unique times CN_L or CN_M (or other values) are found in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[l[3] for l in my_list]` to get the elements at index 3 (4th elements), then simply calling `Counter` on your list will give you the unique elements and their count.

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [["APP", "X", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
           ["APP2", "X", "v3", "CN_M", "2"],
           ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
           ["APP2", "Z", "v3", "CN_M", "2"]]

forth_elts = [l[3] for l in my_list]

print(Counter(forth_elts))


>>> Counter({'CN_M': 2, 'CN_L': 2})
```

And please avoid using keywords and other words such as "str", or "list" to name your variables.

Comment: Thank you, I can continue with this. Of course I don't use a 'list' for the list in the actual code.

How could I get the number of unique values? I want to get a variable with number of unique times that a value occurs at that position in the list. Depending on that, that number of virtual machines must be created.

Comment: `Counter` can be used as a dictionary, so iterating over its `items` will give you the keys and their values. Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Comment: You can find more information about `Counter` in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
    
new_list = [["APP", "X", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
               ["APP2", "X", "v3", "CN_M", "2"],
               ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
               ["APP2", "Z", "v3", "CN_M", "2"]]

#import numpy library
import numpy as np

#convert the list into a numpy array 
arr=np.array(new_list)

#take the 4 th column and then apply the counter 
result=Counter(arr[:,4])
```

Comment: A bit overkill to install numpy and convert this list to an array.

Comment: oh yeah true but wouldn't it be better for large scale vectors?

Comment: Why would it be better? Extracting the 4th elements with a list comprehension will scan through the entire list, just as converting this list to an array does. I don't see where you will gain performance.

Comment: Because of Basic Slicing and Advanced Indexing in numpy it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the data into a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[["APP", "X", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
["APP2", "X", "v3", "CN_M", "2"],
["APP3", "Z", "v3", "CN_L", "2"],
["APP2", "Z", "v3", "CN_M", "2"]]
)

df[4].value_counts()

->

2    4
Name: 4, dtype: int64
```

It will return you a pandas Series which is basically working like a dict so you can do:

```
x = df[4].value_counts()
x["2"] --> 4
```